# Confused about the use of [confused-users]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [confused-users](/questions/tagged/confused-users) tag has eleven questions and no tag wiki or excerpt. Since most [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions are asked by slightly, moderately or completely confused users, and otherwise they might be helped by good [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s, can we get rid of this tag?

Comment: As you are confused (it says so in the title) shouldn't this question be tagged with [tag:confused-users]? :)

Comment: @DavidPostill You're confusing that with [tag:support].  Says so in the question.

Comment: @Ollie Whoosh ....

Comment: A few of the questions under that tag appear to be using it to mean "situations where user X is confused with user Y" (usually, one of X and Y is the "Community" pseudo-user, and the other is the human who actually pushed a given button), which IMHO is a somewhat-legitimate tag meaning. But most of them appear to mean "situations where a user is confused about something," which is obviously a lot less useful.

Comment: You can file me under that section. I'm with the majority :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of various community members, the [confused-users](/questions/tagged/confused-users) tag has been removed from all questions and will be deleted within 24 hours. Confused users are always welcome on Meta, but the tag no longer is!

I've seen some grammar corrections, cleanup of old style 'Possible duplicate' notices and newly found duplicates along the way. That's the way [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s should be carried out; thanks folks for setting an example and keeping Meta.SE a fairly organized place!

[image: BURNINATED]

Comment: @Ollie sorry, didn't get it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer just became outdated. The tag was [reinstated by a user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355780/are-there-chat-rooms-for-per-site-metas) while it had zero questions, but hadn't been actually removed from the system yet. The author of that post continues to edit war over including the tag. Unfortunately, this means that it won't be until the next day that it'll be removed. I've flagged that post, but if the edit war continues, it may take more time.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog seeing that question now has a content dispute lock it will be deleted swiftly.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the picture. Thanks for fixing this crucial mistake, and for keeping an eye on that recent question.

Comment: @Glorfindel sure, always at your service! :D

Comment: And it was [just reused again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355809/377214) by another new user, who also continues to edit war for its inclusion in the same manner as the last post.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog you'd almost think they'd do it on purpose... Thanks for posting the related feature request.

Answer (score 14):

Seems like a classic meta tag of the unwelcome on meta sort. I'd say give it a week or so, see if anyone has any great reasons to keep it, and fire up the reaper :)

Comment: Week is way too much, IMO.... it's only 11 questions, not a major tag.

Comment: Well - I'd like to give it at least a bit of a chance. :D

Comment: Seems like the last user of the tag [continues to war over including the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355780/are-there-chat-rooms-for-per-site-metas), which is preventing the tag from being removed.